# Why the else statement not working here?

Tags: ajax

The following code can't get correct response under the else statment:

```
function ajax_response(){
 if(is_user_logged_in() && check_key() ){
    $result = $do_something;
     if($result){
        ajax_response_string(1,'success!');
      }else{
         ajax_response_string(-1,'there is a problem, please try again!');
      }
 }else{
   ajax_response_string(-1,'you must login first.');
}
```

}

When I log-out and try to click the link that trigger this ajax function, I got a response of "undefined", it is supposed to be "you must login first". Where I've gone wrong?

Comment: first, you have a syntax error !! the opening braket after the last else is not closed, either close it after `ajax_response_string(-1,'you must login first.');` or just remove it.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to close the last else in this post, I just added it.  But in my original code, it is close and not get correct response.

Comment: Print `$result` to verify it is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Comment: if logged out, the die code does not work. seems the code is not triggered when logged out, but, if not triggered, why can still get "undefined" message?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out--  it's not the else statement, it's the ajax response url not working for logged out users. So, my question is not valid anymore. Please close it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at line `$result= //do something` because this line is not terminated. Try this:

```
function ajax_response()
{
     if(is_user_logged_in() && check_key() )
     {
        $result =  doSomething; //error was here as there was no line terminator (;) present.

         if($result)
         {
            ajax_response_string(1,'success!');

         }
          else  
          {
             ajax_response_string(-1,'there is a problem, please try again!');
          }
     }
     else
        {
           ajax_response_string(-1,'you must login first.');
        }

}
```

Comment: it was a mistake when posting this question, I edited my question.

Comment: @Jenny, the 3rd line still reads  `$result = //do something;
`

Comment: sorry, I just edited my question. there is terminator in my original code.

Comment: @Jenny, you still have a syntax error because there is a space in the variable name `$do something;`